# Enable button on drop-down & Text Input Validation

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

The [ ADD ] button enable when all 3 drop-down are selected. Trying to figure out how to now enable the [ ADD ] when the user enter a number amount on the Quantity TextInput

> [image]

**DisplayMode:** `If(IsBlank(drpCategory.Selected.Result) || IsBlank(drpSubCategory.Selected.Result) || IsBlank(drpProductName.Selected.Result),Disabled,Edit)`

TextInput Properties: I have the following regular expression

**BorderColor:** `If(Not(IsMatch(txtQuantity.Text, "\d*"))&&!IsBlank(txtQuantity.Text),RGBA(255,0,0,1),RGBA(0,18,107, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is get the value of the quantity field like following:

```
('#IdOfQuantity').change(function(){
  if(typeof ValueOfQuantity =='number'){
    $( "#IdOfButton" ).prop( "disabled", false );
}
});
```